# What does mean the "B" in a GLM result?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, parameterization

[image]

Comment: 'B' is quite often used for a coefficient estimate on the scale of the linear predictor, though it really ought to be defined somewhere in the paper. The equidistant confidence bounds confirm that interpretation.

Comment: Lower case $b$ is much more common in my experience. Nevertheless,  we are just talking about what it means, not whether it is customary or good notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Scortchi mentioned, B means coefficients. People use B because we use $\beta$ for multiple regression, where

$$y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1+\beta_2x_2+\cdots+\beta_px_p+\epsilon$$

Comment: I think people use $B$ to convey slopes because $A$ is usually reserved for intercepts, as in $Y=A+B\cdot X$.

Comment: @Firebug I think people are lazy or do not know how to type $\beta$ in word...

Comment: Isn't is possible that there a non-identity link function here?